# Syntax troubles with lxml xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm having difficulty understanding the proper syntax to use to get at single elements when parsing XML in Python with lxml.

when I do this:

```
print self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/*",namespaces=self.nsmap)
```

I get a list of subordinate nodes:

```
[<Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}ToolTip at 0x1175830>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}Description at 0x117b6c8>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}DisplayName at 0x117bb48>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}Visibility at 0x117bb90>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}Streamable at 0x117bd88>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}EnumEntry at 0x117b8c0>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}EnumEntry at 0x1214878>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}EnumEntry at 0x1214560>, <Element {http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0}pValue at 0x1214a70>]
```

**So how then do I access, say the first subelement of that list directly with the xpath syntax?**

I've tried:

```
print self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/ToolTip",namespaces=self.nsmap)
```

which gives me an empty set:

```
[]
```

I've also tried specifying namespaces in the xpath which invariably leads to a `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression` error.

Ultimately, I'd like to do this on all sorts of elements such as:

```
self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/pValue")
self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/EnumEntry[@Name='Group']/Value")
self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevHeartbeatTimeoutReg']/Address")
```

The lxml documentation does not seem to cover my use case and anything else I have found about xpath and namespaces seems incomplete.

Comment: You have a namespace `http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0` which you have to register. You can't select elements using their local names as selectors (e.g. `/ToolTip`, `pValue`, etc.) without having the namespace mapped either to a prefix or (if your api supports it) as default. Try `"descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/*[local-name()='ToolTip']"`. If that works, you need to register namespaces (or ignore it in all your expressions like this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to *register* a namespace that is used in your XML source. Usually that is done by assigning it to a *prefix* that you can use in your expressions. Is your `nsmap` variable mapping the namespaces correctly? Choose a prefix (such as `g`, for example):

```
self.nsmap = {'g': 'http://www.genicam.org/GenApi/Version_1_0'}
```

And then use the prefix to qualify your XPath selectors:

```
self.root.xpath("descendant::*[@Name='GevCCP']/g:ToolTip", namespaces=self.nsmap)
```

Comment: Thought I tried this. Must've done something wrong, because this works.

Comment: I think you have to say `namespaces=self.nsmap` as the second param.